# How can I shell_exec this powershell command to get the pid of a process?

Tags: php, powershell

I need to run this command from php within a shell exec but it doesn't work
Im runing a node rtsp monitoring aplication from php so i need to get the pid of the node process every time it runs so when i close the window i can close the process so the cpu doesn't exceed it's limits.

I tried

```
Get-Process | Where-Object ProcessName -eq "node" | ForEach-Object Id
```

and

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.ProcessName -eq "node" } | ForEach-Object { $_.Id }
```

both works in powershell but not in php

this is what i need to run

```
$cmd = "Get-Process | Where-Object ProcessName -eq 'node' | ForEach-Object Id";
        var_dump(shell_exec("powershell.exe -Command " . $cmd));
```

debugging returns null

```
var_dump(shell_exec('powershell.exe ' . $cmd));
```

Comment: Looks like you just need an extra pair of `""` before and after the command?

Comment: That did the work!!! this is it 
$cmd = "Get-Process | Where-Object ProcessName -eq 'node' | ForEach-Object Id";
        var_dump(shell_exec("powershell.exe -Command " . '"' . $cmd . '"')); 
It returns the desired value

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your better approach of enclosing the `$cmd` value in double quotes via string concatenation (`.`) with `'"'`. Additionally, for a robust approach (not needed with your specific command), the update also shows how to `\ `-escape any `"` chars. _embedded_ in the `$cmd` value. I know you're personally aware of the solution, but in order to guide future readers, accepting an answer is still important (unless you see a problem with the answer, in which case I ask you to provide feedback).

Answer (score 0):

PHP's **`shell_exec()`** function, as the name suggests, **uses the host platform's native shell**, which **on Windows** means that **the given command line is passed to `cmd.exe`**.

Therefore, if you want to pass metacharacters such as `|` through to *PowerShell*, you must *quote* them, so that `cmd.exe` doesn't interpret them: You typically do that by enclosing arguments in double quotes (`"..."`) or, less commonly, by quoting (escaping) individual characters with `^`.

The best approach in your case is to ***double-quote* the *entire PowerShell command* using *embedded* double quotes in the command-line string passed** (adapting the technique from your own comment on the question):

```php
$cmd = "Get-Process | Where-Object ProcessName -eq 'node' | ForEach-Object Id";
var_dump(
 shell_exec("powershell.exe -Command " . '"' . str_replace('"', '\"', $cmd) . '"')
);
```

Note the `str_replace()` call, which ensures that any `"` chars. embedded in `$cmd` are properly escaped as `\"`, even though that's not strictly necessary with the specific command in question.

---

Note that **you can greatly streamline your code**, in which case you could even get away without double-quoting.

```php
$cmd = "(Get-Process -ErrorAction Ignore -Name node).Id";
var_dump(shell_exec("powershell.exe -Command " . $cmd));
```